# Gitlab API : Get project's Events with python

Tags: python, json, api, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm coding a script in python and try to get EVENTS from a project with gitlab API.

Here is the code :

```
import gitlab

# private token or personal token authentication
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com/', private_token='My_private_token')

gl.auth()

# Get a target project by ID
project_id = 21847546
project = gl.projects.get(project_id)
```

now when i try to get EVENTS from this project but i got an url to the events and not json object:

```
event=project._links['events']

print(event)
```

Return :

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/21847546/events
```

What should i do in order to get events list in json data form ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of events on a project with:

```
events = project.events.list()
```

Comment: This return a list with all events but no data :

Comment: [<ProjectEvent>, <ProjectEvent>]
<class 'list'>